# function with Math.min() returns first element

Tags: javascript, function, math

I have this simple question where I pass an input made of several numbers to the my function, and want it to output the smallest number.

```
question7 = function(input){
    minimum = Math.min(input);
    console.log(minimum);
}
question7(5,-2,0,1);
```

Why does the console output 5?

Comment: `input` is not all the arguments supplied, only the first one.

Comment: Some basics of [functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions) are good to know ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code you have passed only `5`, because your function accepts only one argument. Try this:

```js
question7 = function(input) {
    var minimum = Math.min(...input);
    console.log(minimum);
}
question7([5, -2, 0, 1]);
```

Here i'm passing an array of numbers and then, in `var minimum = Math.min(...input);` row i have used the **spread syntax** `...` before the argument.

For more info about `...`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

Answer (score 3):

You are only passing `5` to Math.min because that is the first parameter you're calling the `question7` function with.  You want to pass all the `arguments` or parameters to `Math.min`

In this case you could leverage `apply`.

```js
var question7 = function() {
    var minimum = Math.min.apply(Math, arguments);
    console.log(minimum)
}

question7(5,-2,0,1);
```

`apply` takes an array like object and spreads it out into individual arguments and applies them to `this` argument, in this case `Math`

So for this example it takes everything you call `question7`with and applies them to `Math.min` function.

In Javascript `arguments` is a reserved keyword/variable which holds all the parameters which a function was called with.

Answer (score 1):

Because yours function is taken one parameter input